# Flutter dispose() if controller have been initialized (Video Player)

Tags: flutter, dart

My App is disposing a controller everytime I leave the page, however, I am not initializing the controller with `initState()` and am initializing it `onTap`, so I was wondering if it is possible to check if the controller has been initialized to figure out if it should dispose it or not.

The Controller is:

```
VideoPlayerController _controller;
```

And I am initializing it after an `onTap`:

```
onTap: () {
 setState(() {
     _initVideo(file);
 });
}

_initVideo(Future<File> videoFile) async {
    final video = await videoFile;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(video)

      ..setLooping(false)
      ..initialize().then((value) => setState(() {
            _controller.addListener(() {
              setState(() {
              });
            });
          }));
  }
```

And for the dispose I am trying to check whether or not the `VideoController` has been initialized, if it has then `dispose()`, otherwise don't.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution might be to set a flag to true when it's initialized, and check that in your dispose method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's fine. That is actually what I did. I am sorry for not updating the question/ answer, setting a bool when the controller is initialized to true and then checking it when disposing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this widget is disposed after initializing video
if you are using StatefulWidget

```
await videoPlayerController.initialize();
if (!mounted) return;
videoPlayerController.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized